# About Inapppurchases

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have few things to clarify about in app purchases , any feedback is much appreciated.

1. On what would  localizations of the attributes in SKProduct depends on  users iTunes Account or the phone locale ?
2. Can we direct the user to a specific  iTuneStore by default ?

Answer (score 0):

It always works based on the iTunes Account of the user and never on the location. That is an advantage as people may be travelling.

Comment: The OP wasn't talking about the location, but the *locale* of the phone... eg. which language was chosen in the phone preferences